# Mysql2 Error MySQL server has gone away

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

I am getting this error occasionally. I have read some solutions in stackoverflow but they were about rails 2 or mysql. Any help will be appreciated.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: Does message "MySQL server has gone away" tells you anything? Have you tried to connect to your MySQL server in other when having this error (phpMyAdmnin, console)?

Comment: When i refresh the page it works.

Comment: Does this error occur on random pages or in one definite place? Maybe there's a problem with some ineffective query?

Comment: Are you on shared hosting or a private server?

Comment: application is in us and database server is in europe

Comment: So I suggest you should ask your european friends if they having troubles with their mysql server. Tell us if that solved your problem.

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.verify_active_connections! solved it. I created a method and call it as a before filter method

Answer (score 8):

There are numerous causes for the error.  See below page for possible causes.  Perhaps your packet size is set too small.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 6):

I got this error while trying to import a large file through `seeds.rb` with `rake db:seed` by calling one statement:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("path/to/file.sql"))
```

And I kept on getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away...`

---

**SOLUTION**

I resolved this by a combination of two things:

1. Add `reconnect: true` to the database specification in `database.yml`
2. Read the SQL file and execute the statement individually, as such:

   ```
   f = File.new('path/to/file.sql')

   while statements = f.gets("") do
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(statements)
   end
   ```

I had to modify to remove some comments from my SQL file -- they made ActiveRecord throw errors for some reason, but that resolved my problem.

Comment: Oh, and to give credit where due, I adapted the solution code (step 2) from this blog post: http://nathan.seedoftruth.net/post/15237050763/rails-3-load-sql-directly

Answer (score 1):

I experience exactly same issue when I run "rake db:reset" command on my development environment. But I never see this error message when I run "rake db:migrate:reset && rake db:seed".

Though it is very strange, but this may throw some lights on this issue. I am glad if my post leads to a solution somehow.

Comment: I have the same issue running `rake db:reset`. Putting a `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!` just before the source line of the exception fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the server you are hosted on is overloaded and in some cases the MySQL server can not execute a query. Ask your hosting provider about performance monitoring tools, or tell him about this problem directly. This error message should be enough for them to give you an answer.