# MySQL server has gone away error in delayed_job task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm trying to debug a scenario in which the delayed_job process dies under certain circumstances because of a `Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away` error.

My setup is a bit complex, but I tried to whittle it down to the basics. The `run` method in the `ClustalwFlowTask` class is handled as a background job. It basically runs a `clustalw2` command (a program that does multiple sequence alignment for DNA and proteins)

The details of the command and any error that occurs during its execution should be logged in the flow_tasks table and not caught by delayed_job (see the `update_attribute` statements).

```
require 'open3'
class ClustalwFlowTask < FlowTask

  def run
    # setup code ------

    # fasta is a file object
    cmd = "clustalw2 -INFILE=#{fasta.path}"

    Rails.logger.info "[INFO #{Time.now}] #{self} running #{cmd}"
    #update_attribute(:command, cmd)

    raw_stdin,  raw_stdout, raw_stderr = Open3.popen3(cmd)

    Rails.logger.info "*********** RAW STDERR: #{raw_stderr} ************"

    stdin, stdout, stderr = [raw_stdin,  raw_stdout, raw_stderr].map do |io|
      s = io.read.strip rescue nil
      io.close
      s
    end

    Rails.logger.info "*************** #{stderr} *******************"
    unless stderr.blank?
      Rails.logger.info "============  THERE IS AN ERROR  ============"
      #update_attribute(:error, stderr)
      return false
    end

    # more code here -----
end
```

The weird behavior starts when a user doesn't have the `clustalw2` binary installed, that is if the stderr variable in the method is not blank. Note that I uncommented all the `update_attribute` statements from the `#run` method during debugging, so there is no apparent MySQL involvement. (One of my first hunches was that the stderr message is too big or contains something that causes the MySQL server to shut down, but that doesn't seem to be the case)

The delayed_job log contains the following:

```
2012-03-26T09:19:25-0700: [Worker(delayed_job host:JadeDragon.local pid:8998)] ClustalwFlowTask failed with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: DELETE FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`id` = 107 - 0 failed attempts
```

What seems to be happening here is that delayed_job attempted to delete a successful task from the db, but was unable to do so because the mysql connection had been severed. This occurs after the `return false` statement in the `ClustalwFlowTask#run` code, since that's when, according to delayed_job, the task is finished successfully.

The development log has this:

```
================  THERE IS AN ERROR  ================
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`id` = 110
Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: DELETE FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`id` = 110
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: ROLLBACK
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: ROLLBACK
closed MySQL connection
```

I'm running out of ideas on how to debug this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is mysql still running after these events?  Is the problem reproducible or sporadic?  Have you checked the mysql logs on the server? Is there enough memory on the server?  Also check the answers and link on this related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807012/mysql2-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: Yes, the mysql server is still running. The event is always reproducible under the same circumstances I described. The mysql logs don't show any error. I have seen the list of possible causes for the "server has gone away" error, but nothing seems to be applicable here.

Comment: @AndreaSingh, Did you find a solution to this problem ? I am facing the exact problem. I tried reconnect: true but that did not work either.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding `reconnect: true` to your database.yml

Comment: Was looking at this for quite some time. This fixed me right up. Rails 3.2.7